# Using Jquery to selecting an id with curly brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2007, graph

I've got such a frustrating question for which I'm convinced there is an easy answer. Unfortunately I can't seem to find it anywhere! I have a table which I have no control over (SharePoint) and the table ID which has been allocated contains curly brackets:

e.g. `<table id="{ACDC3234-D009-4889-931A-FCC069613AB6}-{EF2BF0FD-7927-4194-910F-0FE83EC4F118}"></table>`

How can I select the table using JQuery whilst maintaining the brackets?

The code as it stands is:

```
    $(function(){

$('/{#{ACAC3258-D068-4799-931A-FCC069613AB6}-{EF2BF0FD-7927-4194-910F-0FE83EC4F118}}/').visualize({type: 'bar', width: '420px'});


});
```

I am trying to use JQuery Graphing Tool, Visualise.

Any help on this would be really greatly appreciated!

Many Thanks!

Comment: Confused as to why you have `/{` at the start and the extra `}/` at the end?

Comment: Thanks for all the help! The 'getElementById' answer below worked perfectly! I knew it was something simple. Thanks a lot to all who answered!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest option is to call `$(document.getElementById("{ACDC3234-D009-4889-931A-FCC069613AB6}-{EF2BF0FD-7927-4194-910F-0FE83EC4F118}"))`.

You can also try escaping the braces with `\` characters (which must themselves be escaped in the JS string literal):

```
$('#\\{ACDC3234-D009-4889-931A-FCC069613AB6\\}-\\{EF2BF0FD-7927-4194-910F-0FE83EC4F118\\}')
```

Comment: Both of your solutions will work (in Chrome at least) - just tested: http://jsbin.com/olube3

Answer (score 4):

Just in addition, [reading documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) helps:

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as `` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ `` ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: `\\`.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's an invalid ID, you probably can't use the ID selector. This might work though:

```
$('table[id="{ACDC3234-D009-4889-931A-FCC069613AB6}-{EF2BF0FD-7927-4194-910F-0FE83EC4F118}"]')
```

Now you're using any-attribute-selector (whatever that's called). Since you can put anything in an attribute, you can (I think!) search for it.

Maybe jQuery won't allow it...

**edit**
jQuery 1.3.2 allows it: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/VHpFb/

Answer (score 2):

That ID is invalid in HTML4 and for that reason you can't assume that every browser or tool will be able to process it.

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/types.html#type-name):

> `ID` and `NAME` tokens must begin with a letter (`[A-Za-z]`) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits (`[0-9]`), hyphens (`"-"`), underscores (`"_"`), colons (`":"`), and periods (`"."`).

However, it's probably worth noting that HTML5 (which is partially a restandardisation of how existing browsers treat HTML) [does remove those restrictions](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class), so despite my warning it's likely that there *is* another solution which *will* work more often than not.